# Computation of Expectation

Tags: probability, limits, random-variables, expected-value

I am stuck working an exercise. The setting is given as follows:

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables defined on some probability space where 
\begin{equation}
P\left(X_n = \frac{1}{n}\right) = P\left(X_n = -\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
for every $n$. Let $Y = \sum_{n\geq 1} X_n$.

---

The first question I got was to show that $|Y|<\infty$ almost surely. Which I managed to do after some time.

The second question is to compute the expectation of $Y$ (using the previous result). I'm not entirely sure how I should do this. From the previous result I found that $E(Y)<\pi/\sqrt{6}$ and from a symmetry argument it would seem that the expectation should be equal to $0$. Yet I have no idea how I could show this. Is it allowed to interchange limits and expectation in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There is  no need for interchange of sum and expectation .

Each $X_n$ has  a symmetric distribution. Together with independence this implies that $Y$ also has  a symmetric distribution. If you have already proved that $Y$ has finite expectation it follows that $EY=E(-Y)$ so $EY=0$.

Note: The fact that $Y$ has symmetric distribution is  consequence of the fact that the sequences $(X_n)$ and $(-X_n)$ induce the  same distribution  on $\mathbb R^{\infty}$.

Comment: How is the independence of the $X_n$ important for $Y$ being a symmetric distribution?

Comment: @JelleDijkstra Independence is important. You cannot say that $X+Y$ has  symmetric distribution whenever $X$ and $Y$ have a symmetric distribution.